# Alter Index within a Script

Tags: sql-server, index-maintenance

I've been reading about SQL Server Index Fragmentation and how to rebuild/reorganize. I'm curious on how to write a script about it. I have a script that will generate the table with the table index and display the fragmentation in percent:

```
SELECT 
    dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
    dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
    dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                             AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE 
    indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY 
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

Can I add `ALTER INDEX __NAME_OF_INDEX__ ON __NAME_OF_TABLE__ REBUILD` to this script or do I have to write a new script.

I found http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/ but am not sure on how I use it properly.

I'm new to database administration and am trying to setup a maintenance plan that will rebuild indexes when they hit a certain threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're new to the DBA role then go to this site:

[OLA](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

What you're trying to do has already been done.

Any DBA should have this site on their list of favourites.

Comment: Ostensibly, this advice applies even if you're *not* new to the DBA role.  Ola Hallengren's scripts are indispensable.